# Best way to load 50+ images from server in Android

Tags: android, image, web-services, asynchronous

I have an issue, i have created an android appliaction, and i have to load more than 50 image at once. I have been loading images as async task but when i got from server 50 picture ids it is too much. I need some best practice how to do that. I am limited to 1 picture whit 1 call. and the picture comes as multipart object so i need to call async tasks.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consider using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

Picasso is A **powerful image downloading and caching library** for Android(straight copy from their site)

Picasso will handle the **downloading and caching of images**, so you don't have to worry about any of that

Also it does the work on other thread, so your **UI thread isn't blocked**!

Here's an example code of loading image to a ImageView from their site:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Hi I have to have async task @Pasi sorry. I need to get them as multipart data object.

Comment: I don't see why would you need to use async task. Is there more than one image in a single request?

Comment: No, there is just 1 image but the image is coming as byte stream and i need to use async task. I got and send images like these: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: Isn't multipart used on the client side? Is the Android application acting as a HTTP server? You can extend Picasso to support this, so you get caching and everything else for free using the Downloader interface

Comment: We use these kind of communication because the server has to little RAM. I have done it for simple image, I have gathered the bytes and put together so i has the picture, then i added it to my picture array. but now i have issue when i have 50+ images to download. I have to use my way of downloading the images, just don't know how what is the best practice to do that with async tasks

Comment: I wouldn't myself really use AsyncTasks for anything, they're simple to use but it comes with cost, couple of quick searches and you'll figure why

If I were you I would go ahead and implement a custom downloader interface for the kind of data you're receiving and enjoy the powerful threading and caching that picasso provides!

But then again, you can do whatever you want, its your code.

Comment: No offense Pasi, I like your answer, i gave to it already an upvote. I do not really can use 3rd party libs. I implement the solution myself, but if you say that not use async task, can you please tell me what. Anyway thanks for your answer.